# Trouble with Selecting Records between Two Dates

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table of transactions. I need to query the table for only the transactions between a given set of dates.

This should be a simple SQL query. I have the following:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Main
WHERE Main.InvoDate BETWEEN #06/15/19# AND #06/31/19#;
```

But when I run it, I get

> Syntax error in date in query expression 'Main.InvoDate BETWEEN #06/15/19# AND #06/31/19#'

Not sure where to go from here. Everything that I have seen seems to say that this code block should work. I have tried "2019" as opposed to "19", and I have also tried "ddmmyyyy".

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are only 30 days in June.

Comment: Then we both are. I've done it before, that's how I noticed. The error message from Access wasn't very helpful.